# Uses of Static Electricity

Tags: electricity, charge

Is it possible to store static electricity in any type of battery and can they be used in electric appliances (lightbulbs mainly)?

Comment: Of course, it's just not very useful because there is very little energy in the kind of static electricity that you can encounter. Even lightning only equates to a couple of gallons of gasoline, or so. It's not even worth thinking about capturing either.

Answer (score 4):

Yes indeed. Assuming that by *storing static electricity* you mean storing an electric charge directly then there is currently a lot of interest in devices called [supercapacitors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor) that do exactly this. In particular they are being investigated for [use in electric vehicles](http://www.economist.com/news/science-and-technology/21606715-new-sort-storage-device-gives-lithium-ion-batteries-run-their).

Storing a high charge density in a capacitor is hard because it produces a very strong electric field. Then you need to worry about dielectric breakdown, leakage, and so on. Supercapacitors use a relatively low charge density but have an enormous surface area, and the result is they can store a great deal of charge in a small volume.

Comment: Is it right to say a supercapacitor stores charge? Isn't what it stores energy? Accomplished by a rearrangement of charge. When you "charge" a supercapacitor, isn't the charge flowing *in* one side/lead exactly counteracted by the charge flowing *out* the other?

Comment: A supercapacitor, like all capacitors, produces a charge separation. The point is that it doesn't transform the energy to another form like, for example, charging a battery where the energy is stored as chemical energy.

Answer (score 1):

Rubbing a balloon generates a static electric charge. Some electrons are separated of their nuclei. Electrons have a repulsive force on each other. They are located on the spherical shape of the balloon. Uniformly distributed because of their repulsion.

Touching the ballon, these electrons flow - a small electic shock. Moving electrons are called electric current. If current is too low, we build a bigger balloon. So it should be possible to build a battery?

**No**, because the static electricity does not produce a constant electric current. The balloon is discharged, once touched. Instead of thinking of a battery, I like to think of it as a **capacitor**. LED lights of a bike sometimes are buffer with one of these. Unlike a battery based on chemical reaction, static electricity in this example has to be recharged. Rubbing the balloon is not practicable.

Have a look at the **Van-de-Graaff generator** generator. This device constantly generates static electricity. Educating and fun if you touch it.

Comment: The balloon acts very much like a capacitor.